# I'm running a function with a new timer every time I press a button; I don't know how to access the timer from a previous press

Tags: java, timer

I  have a function press(int id) that opens/closes the door depending on whether it's open/closed and if the timer is on or off. The way it works is:

Door starts closed. I press it once and it opens with a 5s timer set up which will close the door automatically

If I press it again, before the timer runs out (still open) it will disable the timer and keep the door open forever

If I press it again, while the door is open forever, it will close.

The issue is that.. I go to press it once. It works, and the timer is set. However when I press it a second time, I call t.cancel, but that doesn't cancel the timer. With the errors it gives (failed test cases) its very clear that the timer still finishes, and closes the door at exactly 5 seconds. (I tried 50ms before 5 seconds and it was open; 50ms after 5 seconds it was closed).

I assume it's because when I run Press the second time, it creates a new timer t, and THAT's the timer that's being cancelled on the second press.

How do I cancel the first press timer so it will work how I want it?

Small note: I already tried pulling the timer out and just using it as a variable for the object that calls press, however that doesn't work (I tested to check) because apparently if you call cancel on a timer, you can not re-activate it you have to create a new one. Thus, it has to stay within the press(int) function.

---

---

Code of the function:

```
    public void press(int id) {

    Timer t2 = new Timer();
    if (okIds.contains(id)) {// if the remote is accepted by the door

        // if the delay is set to 0 the door stays open
        // timer is not enabled (disabled by default)
        if (!isOpen() && CLOSE_DELAY == 0) {
            controller.open();
        }
        // if the delay is set to a viable number and the door is closed
        // open the door, enable the delay, set timer to the given time
        else if (!isOpen() && CLOSE_DELAY >= 0) {
            System.out.println("space 1");
            controller.open();
            isTimerEnabled = true;
            t2.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    controller.close();
                    t2.cancel();
                }
            }, CLOSE_DELAY);
        }
        // now all cases for the door being closed is handled.


        // if the door is open, while the timer is enabled (timer running)
        // we disable the timer and keep the door open.
        else if (isOpen() && isTimerEnabled) {
            System.out.println("space 2");
            try{
                t2.cancel();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.print("catch");
            }
            //t.purge();
            // door should still be open. do not need to re-open
            controller.open();
            isTimerEnabled = false;

        }
        // if the door is open, while the timer is disabled (open forever)
        // we just close the door
        // then reset the timer for the next press
        else if (isOpen() && !isTimerEnabled) {
            System.out.println("space 3");
            controller.close();
            isTimerEnabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have "t2" be a class variable, and then you need to create a new timer right before you call schedule on it.

```
t2 = new Timer();
t2.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                controller.close();
                t2.cancel();
            }
        }, CLOSE_DELAY);
```